# How do I check if a form is being submitted with a new value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple form. Now, what I need to do is hide a div element if the form is being submitted with a new value which is not the same as the one searched the first time.

how do i do it?

I am using jquery and ruby on rails

Here is the code

```
<%= form_tag home_path, :method => "post", :name=>"onLoad",  :remote=> true  do %>
                <div class="containePrepend">
                    <% if params[:searchedValue].nil? == true%>

                    <%=text_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => 'Please enter the product to continue' %>
                    <%else%>
                    <%=text_field_tag 'search', nil, :value => params[:searchedValue]%>
                    <%end%>

                </div>
                <%= button_tag(:type => 'submit', :id => "buttonSubmit") do %>
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

The form is being submitted via ajax, which `appends` to the div

```
<div class="product_first_roll"></div>
<div class="product_old_roll"></div>
```

Now, if the value is searched is newer than the previous one. I want to hide contents from the old search inside

```
<div class="product_first_roll"></div>
<div class="product_old_roll"></div>
```

And only show the new one inside

```
<div class="product_first_roll"></div>
<div class="product_old_roll"></div>
```

Sorry if it sounds too complicated or messed up. If i just know how to check if a form is being submitted with a new value, i can figure the rest out.

Thanks

Comment: Include the code you've written so far to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

Just have a single div and keep on updating the same div with new search results after every search, so that there no need of hiding the old div.

Alternatively,

Add an hidden field in the form like `<%= hidden_field_tag :previous_search_value, params[:searchValue] %>` and now in the `controller action`,

```
@hidden = params[:previous_search_value].eql?(params[:searchValue])
```

and now after this action done, in the success function or in .js.erb file add the following logic to hide your div.

```
<% if @hidden %>
  $("#product_old_roll").hide();
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: actually i have to have two divs. Plus the if two different terms are searched, that means two different sort of results will be displayed. It will be pointless to have both type of results being shown to the user. So i thought hiding it and showing again with the new value will be a good idea.

Comment: for some reason it happens to be blank `"previous_search_value"=>""`

Comment: is it like, we cant pass in a param into a hidden_field_tag?

Comment: After the controller action, all the params values will be cleared and hence we wont be able to get the form parameters in params in view file. So we need to get the value in view in some other way. like initialize two values as `@previous_search and @current_search`in the controller and use them in the view.

Comment: I actually did it some other way. Thanks :)